Use Windows 11 Firewall to allow an executable to use only a specific subnet and block traffic in other directions
I want to create a Powershell script that uses the Windows 11 Firewall to allow an executable (C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\app.exe) to use only a specific subnet (192.168.4.0/24) and block traffic in other directions.
This is a ChatGPT attempt because I'm a novice with Windows FW.
# Define the executable path
$exePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\app.exe"

# Define the allowed network
$allowedNetwork = "192.168.4.0/24"

# Create a rule to allow the executable to access the allowed network
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow MyApp.exe on 192.168.4.0/24" -Direction Outbound -Program $exePath -RemoteAddress $allowedNetwork -Action Allow

# Create a rule to block the executable from accessing any other networks
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block MyApp.exe on other networks" -Direction Outbound -Program $exePath -RemoteAddress "Any" -Action Block


However, I'm also having trouble debugging the logs; since I have enabled the %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\Pfirewall.log (I've put Yes in each field), I can just see the header but no entries.

Are you trying to allow inbound or outbound connections?

I thought that outbounds were enough, but since you asked, both are better!
